# Understanding syntax of Generic methods

Tags: c#, generics

I am reading C# In Depth book and here is the example:

```
List<TOutput> ConvertAll<TOutput>(Converter<T, TOutput> converter)
```

I don't understand this part:  `ConvertAll<TOutput>`

When he is dissecting his example he also says: `"The method's name is ConvertAll and it has a single param of  Converter<T, TOutput>`

See still it doesn't say what/why is  in`ConvertAll<TOutput>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that your confusion stems from the fact that the name `TOutput` appears earlier in the text of the program than its declaration.

Here is what is going on - recall that the syntax for defining a regular method is as follows:

```
return_type method_name ( param1_type param1, param2_type param2, ... )
```

Generic methods add angular brackets after the method name:

```
method_name <gnenric_type_param1, generic_type_param2, ...> ( param1_type param1, param2_type param2, ... )
```

So now your method looks like this:

```
return_type ConvertAll<TOutput> ( param1_type param1, param2_type param2, ... )
```

What's the return type? It's `List<TOutput>`. `TOutput` comes from the type arguments in angular brackets, but it is used in the return type, which is *before* the angular brackets:

```
List<TOutput> ConvertAll<TOutput> ( param1_type param1, param2_type param2, ... )
```

The rest of the declaration is simple: you have only one parameter, `Converter<T, TOutput> converter`, which uses the `TOutput` generic type parameter of the method, along with `T`, presumably a generic type parameter of the class. This shows you how a method of a generic class can add generic type parameters of its own to be used alongside the generic type parameters of the class in which the method is declared.

Answer (score 1):

`TOutput` is the type parameter that specifies the type used in the List that gets returned. Without the generic type parameter, you would have to do something like:

```
List<object> ConvertAll(Converter<T, object> converter)
```

Which, obviously, is an extremely poor substitute to something that can be of a specific type.

Comment: but doesn't List<TOutput> its self has a <TOutput> ? So wasn't that enough to tell it the type?

Comment: `List<TOutput>` only consumes the generic type that the method declares. The actual declaration of that generic type is in `ConvertAll<TOutput>`.

Comment: Actually, that exactly's how you'd use `ConvertAll`. See the example in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73fe8cwf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). You don't need to specify the type because it can be inferred from the parameter (of type `Convert<T,object>`

Comment: @MattBurland - Calling `ConvertAll` and writing the method `ConvertAll` are two different things. There is no type inference when you're defining the method.

Comment: I thought `List<TOutput>` is a returning list of that type. Right? I'm new at C#

Answer (score 1):

The part

```
<TOutput>
```

specifies a type that is supplied when you want to use the method in code.  You might write for example

```
var result = ConvertAll<int>(converter);
```

to make use of the method.

That prevents the need to create a separate method for each possible return type, where only the return type is different.

I purposefully used the `var` keyword above to illustrate that the `<int>` after `ConvertAll` specifies a type that is "dropped in" to the generic method definition by the compiler.  That is the part of your code where you make the *generic* method *concrete* (meaning you specify concrete types to use).

**UPDATE**

As mentioned in my comment, here is a method with that takes a type parameter that is not used for the return type.

```
static void Swap<T>(ref T lhs, ref T rhs)
{
    T temp;
    temp = lhs;
    lhs = rhs;
    rhs = temp;
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb.aspx

Comment: so it is the "return type" of the method?

Comment: The "return type" is `List<int>` in the example I give.  Since I specified type `int`, `int` is "dropped in" wherever `TOutput` appears in the method definition.

Comment: so my confusion is this: We already tell the method that its return type is List<TOutput>, which in code can be int, double,etc..  and we also tell the method that its input is that converter param we passed in... A method has an input and an output, so what is that extra <TOutput> doing there? :D

Comment: also what would it be if the method's return type was "void" ?

Comment: In that case, you would not need `TOutput` per se (note the name, which is arbitrary, *implies* to a human reader that it is an output type).  A method may still take a type parameter for use within the implementation.  I'll update my answer with an example.

Comment: You can't use a return type of `void` since `void` is not a type, it's a C# token that indicates that there is no return value.  If a return type is expected and `void` is supplied instead the compiler will throw an error.

Answer (score 1):

This is a generic method inside a generic class.

In general the list of type parameters for a generic type or method is given after the name of the type or method.  Examining the above:

```
List<TOutput> ConvertAll<TOutput>(Converter<T, TOutput> converter)
```

In this instance the type parameter is after the method name `ConvertAll`.  Whatever type you use when you call `ConvertAll` will be used to determine the resultant type.  The single parameter here is a function that takes a `T` (the type of items in the list) and returns a `TOutput`.  This is run against every item in the list and the results are returned in a new `List<TOutput>`.

Here's an example of usage:

```
List<int> intlist = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
List<double> converted = intlist.ConvertAll<double>(i => (double)i);
```

In this case the type `double` has been substituted for the type parameter `TOutput`, and `int` is the `List`'s `T` parameter, so the effective signature of the generic method call is:

```
List<double> ConvertAll(Converter<int, double> converter)
```

In many cases the compiler will figure out the type parameter for you based on the type returned by the parameter, so you can often skip the explicit specifier like this:

```
List<double> converted = intlist.ConvertAll(i => (double)i);
```

The generic method gives you the flexibility to specify any type of conversion without the `List<T>` class needing to have explicit handlers for it.  Just like you can create a `List` of any type you can pass a conversion function to `ConvertAll` with any output type and it'll happily process it for you, returning the appropriate type of `List`.